# Telegram watch video directly from link

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

I'm new in telegram bots. And I'm trying to scrap links to a video from my website and watch it directly without downloading(the video on a server). So I'm already scrapped and I have video links. So my question is: Is it possible to use built-in media player to watch directly video from the link ?

I'm expecting to get answer my question and for example, get small example of it on Python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

# replace with your Telegram bot token
bot = Bot(token='YOUR_TOKEN_HERE')
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

# define a command handler that takes a video URL as an argument
@dp.message_handler(commands=['watch'])
async def watch_video(message: types.Message):
    video_url = message.get_args()
    video = types.InputMediaVideo(media=video_url)
    await bot.send_video(chat_id=message.chat.id, video=video)

# start the bot
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(dp.start_polling())
    loop.run_forever()
```

In this example, we first create a Bot instance using our Telegram bot token and a Dispatcher instance using a MemoryStorage. We define a command handler that takes a video URL as an argument and creates an InputMediaVideo object from the URL. We then send the video to the user using the send_video method of the Bot object.

Note that the video must be in a format supported by Telegram, which includes MP4 videos encoded with H.264 and AAC codecs. If the video is not in a supported format, you may need to transcode it before sending it to Telegram. Also, this example assumes that the video URL is passed as an argument to the /watch command. You can modify the code to extract the video URL from a different source if necessary.

Comment: Is it will work if video file over 1gb for example ?